# Spring Batch Repeat Template Stuck for more than 3 minutes

Tags: java, spring, websphere, spring-batch

I had created a file generation spring batch within an Application Server (IBM WAS 8.5.5) and it is trigger through an Async Task run within the same JVM with Application Server. Its been working fine all the while for 2 years.

However, recently there is one issue happen to this spring batch which the Repeat Template take 3 minutes to respond. Below are the line capture in logs, it shows the different between count 81 and 82 is 3 minutes. But other counts are working fine as it respond less than 1 second.

```
2018-03-14 10:18:13.126 [WorkManager.DefaultWorkManager : 441] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - [user1] - Repeat operation about to start at count=79
2018-03-14 10:18:13.127 [WorkManager.DefaultWorkManager : 441] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - [user1] - Repeat operation about to start at count=80
2018-03-14 10:18:13.127 [WorkManager.DefaultWorkManager : 441] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - [user1] - Repeat operation about to start at count=81
2018-03-14 10:21:25.178 [WorkManager.DefaultWorkManager : 441] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - [user1] - Repeat operation about to start at count=82
2018-03-14 10:21:25.178 [WorkManager.DefaultWorkManager : 441] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - [user1] - Repeat operation about to start at count=83
2018-03-14 10:21:25.178 [WorkManager.DefaultWorkManager : 441] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - [user1] - Repeat operation about to start at count=84
```

Below are my spring batch configuration

```
 <job id="sprBatchOnlineBulkPaymentJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="OnlinebulkPaymentSibs_step1">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="bulkPaymentTableReader" writer="bulkPaymentFileWriter"   chunk-completion-policy="bulkFileCompletionPolicy"  />
                <transaction-attributes isolation="DEFAULT" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
            </tasklet>
        </step> 
    </job>


    <bean id="bulkFileCompletionPolicy" class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.DefaultResultCompletionPolicy"/>
```

I had check the server verbosegc file and it show in that particular moment my server still have 1GB of free memory. I need advice on what could possible went wrong between count 81 and 82 because it take 3 minutes to respond compare to others is just less than 1 second.

Comment: Did you resolve that exception ,Even i stuckup with the same context count not able to complete as ExecutionStatus still says CONTINUABLE not FINISHED